# I have files that the Python Requests function has incorrectly coded, expanding special chars

Tags: python, utf-8, python-requests, iso-8859-1

I have a large set of files that were mangled by Python Requests r.text conversion.  The original was UTF-8 but Requests assumed ISO-8859-1 so, for example, e acute has expanded from hex `C3A9` to `C383C2A9`.  There a bunch of these.  Is there any way to fix this with Python?
BTW, I now know how to set the encoding before writing to a file 
  `r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding`
but is there any way to fix this now without tracking down every translation?

I guess that if I read as ISO-8859-1, I'll have two new characters that won't convert back to one ETF-8 char, right?

Comment: if you work with file then you should rather use `r.content` which give you raw data - without encoding - and write it with byte mode `"wb"`

Comment: Encoding to ISO-8859-1, then decoding as UTF-8 should reverse that.